# Must I normalize inputs into a perceptron that uses a sigmoid activation function?

Tags: neural-networks

I am building a neural network. Each perceptron in the network uses a [sigmoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) activation function.

Must I normalize my inputs (which currently range form 0 to 1200)? I ask this because the sigmoid function approaches 1 as the input to it approaches infinity. Hence, if my input is not between 0 and 1, I'm afraid that the sigmoid will always return 1.

Answer (score 7):

The inputs should be scaled to the so-called "active range" of the activation function, or, in other words, the area of the function curve where the derivative of the function is clearly non-zero. This is done for backpropagation to work properly, since it uses activation function derivatives, and `~ 0` derivatives imply extremely small (insignificant) changes to NN weights (no learning). For sigmoid, the active range lies somewhere between `-sqrt(3)` and `sqrt(3)`. You may scale inputs to that range.

Also, yes: sigmoid will always output values in `(0;1)`, because that's sigmoid's range. You will need to scale NN outputs to the necessary ranges.